# Turn on row names in renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

I am displaying a table in Shiny and want to use *renderDataTable* but it is not displaying the row names which are important to me. *renderTable* displays the row names fine but does not look as nice.

I have:

```
 output$tab<-renderDataTable({tabplot()})
```

and have tried:

```
output$tab<-renderDataTable({tabplot()}, include.rownames=TRUE)
```

with no luck.

Comment: Just a note, although it may not be relevant to you here, the answer here may depend on which "renderDataTable" call you're using. This function is available in shiny as well as DT. Are you using the "DT" package? Is your table a data.table?

Comment: Looking at the literature, it looks like "rownames=TRUE" should replace your "include.rownames=TRUE"

Comment: Unfortunately when I add rownames=TRUE my whole table disappears.

Comment: That probably means you're using shiny::renderDataTable(), try with the DT package instead: DT::renderDataTable() (make sure you've got DT installed and enabled, of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, it works for me, although I can't fully reproduce your dataset.

```
    output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable( tabplot(), rownames = TRUE )
    })
```

I've forced the use of the DT package, and also enclosed the table creation in a "datatable" call, which includes the option to enable rownames. I think you'd also be able to enable that option in the creation of "tablplot()", but it should definitely work here either way.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I came back to this part of my project today and you were completely right. Just installed and included the DT library and got the row names. Cheers

Comment: No worries, Mike. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: what exactly is the dataframe here?

Comment: @Ben I haven't done this stuff in awhile, but I believe the `tablplot()` function is returning the data to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
renderDataTable(cbind(my_rows = rownames(data), data))
```

instead of

```
renderDataTable(data)
```

works too.

Thanks to: [Yihui](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/s9r9nM37sNM#:%7E:text=At%20the%20moment%2C%20you%20have%20to%20bind%20the%20row%20names%20as%20a%20column%20in%20the%20data%2C%20e.g.%0A%0ArenderDataTable(cbind(names%20%3D%20names(data)%2C%20data))%0A%0Ainstead%20of%0A%0ArenderDataTable(data))