# R Shiny Generate Table with Reactive Inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set up a conceptually simple chain of logic in a shiny app for R.

I have a function that generates a table.

```
OutputTable <- FindMarkers(P15CellsSeurat, 0, 1, min.pct = 0.25)
```

The table generated in the above example is a comparison of groups 0 and 1.  What i would like to do is make this interactive in shiny so that a user can select which of the groups 0-4 they would like to compare and then receive a table corresponding to their selections.

I have tried to set this up and this is what it looks like:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
 mainPanel(h1("Title", align = "center"),
              tabsetPanel(type="tabs",

                         tabPanel("Compare Clusters",
                                   h4("Compare Gene Expression Between Clusters", align = "center"),
                                   br(),
                                   plotOutput("plot_P15Clusters_dup"),
                                   fluidRow(
                                   column(6,
                                   checkboxGroupInput("input$ClusterVariable1",
                                                      label = h4("Clusters"),
                                                      choices = list("Cluster 0" = 1,
                                                                     "Cluster 1" = 2,
                                                                     "Cluster 2" = 3,
                                                                     "Cluster 3" = 4,
                                                                     "Cluster 4" = 5),
                                                      selected = 1)
                                   ),
                                   column(6,
                                   checkboxGroupInput("input$ClusterVariable2",
                                                      label = h4("Clusters"),
                                                      choices = list("Cluster 0" = 1,
                                                                     "Cluster 1" = 2,
                                                                     "Cluster 2" = 3,
                                                                     "Cluster 3" = 4,
                                                                     "Cluster 4" = 5),
                                                      selected = 2)
                                   ),
                                   submitButton("Submit")),
                                   dataTableOutput("Table6")),
)
)
)
```

.

```
     #server.R
        shinyServer(function(input, output){

    output$cluster.markers <- renderUI(FindMarkers(P15CellsSeurat, input$`input$ClusterVariable1`, c(input$`input$ClusterVariable2`), min.pct = 0.25))

      output$Table6 <- renderDataTable(
        cluster.markers,
        options = list(
          lengthMenu = list(c(10, 20, 30,-1),c('10','20','30','ALL')),
          pageLength = 10))

ClusterVariable1 <- reactive({input$ClusterVariable1})
ClusterVariable2 <- reactive({input$ClusterVariable2})

})
```

I tried to select out only the relevant sections of the code so i apologize if there are any missing ().

I consistantly get an error saying Error: object 'cluster.markers' not found.

So any assistance getting the cluster.markers object to be properly generated would be a great help!

Thanks for your help and patience as i try to improve my understanding of how to use reactive objects in shiny.

Comment: Just replace `output$cluster.markers <- renderUI(` with `cluster.markers <- reactive(` then add parenthesis like `renderDataTable(cluster.markers(),`

Comment: also avoid calling your input : `"input$ClusterVariable2"` use `"ClusterVariable1"` instead

Comment: Hi Guys thanks these suggestions worked perfectly.  I do have one additional problem though.  I lost the rownames of the table which are a critical part for data interpretation.  I have tried adding "rownames = TRUE" to a variety of places with no luck.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881741/turn-on-row-names-in-renderdatatable