# How to show rownames in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have my dataframe with rownames and colnames. When I launch the app, everything works, and the dataframe returns correctly, but without rownames; however, I would like to return rownames too. I tried `renderTable()` and that :

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
    output$tableau<-renderDataTable({
       tabSvol<-data.frame(S=c(1,2,3),Vol=c(12,56,23))
       rownames(tabSvol)<-c("T1","T2","T3")
       tabSvol
    })
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881741/turn-on-row-names-in-renderdatatable?rq=1?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use renderDataTable or the DT package, you can simply add rownames = TRUE parameter to your renderTable() function and it will do the job.

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$tableau<-renderTable({
tabSvol<-data.frame(S=c(1,2,3),Vol=c(12,56,23))
rownames(tabSvol)<-c("T1","T2","T3")
tabSvol
}, rownames = TRUE)
})
```